# How to add a subtitle to a beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

Now i have a frametitle named "AAA", but now i've got a subtitle named "bbb", is there some ways to add "bbb" as a  subtitle. The following is the codes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{AAA}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

thanks

Answer (score 37):

There is also a command:

```
\framesubtitle{<subtitle>}
```

Quoting the Beamer user guide:

> `\framesubtitle<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨frame subtitle text⟩}`
>
> If present, a subtitle will be shown in a smaller font below the main
>   title. Like the `\frametitle` command, this command can be given
>   anywhere in the frame, since the frame title is actually typeset only
>   when everything else has already been typeset. Example:
>
> ```
>      \begin{frame}
>        \frametitle<presentation>{Frame Title Should Be in Uppercase.}
>        \framesubtitle{Subtitles can be in lowercase if they are full sentences.}
>        Frame contents.
>      \end{frame}
> ```

Comment: what's the meaning of " this command can be given anywhere in the frame, since the frame title is actually typeset only when everything else has already been typeset" ?

Comment: I guess this means that you can put it even at the end of a frame, like `\begin{frame}{title}some text\framesubtitle{subtitle}\end{frame}`.

Comment: You can put it multiple number of times, so it is possible to change it, while the frame is still being shown.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
\begin{frame}{title}{subtitle}
content here
\end{frame}
```

Be careful if the content starts with `{` as a scope limiter.

Comment: If I ommit subtitle the compiler doesn't complain. Why is that the case? If subtitle is a mandatory argument shouldn't always be passed?